# How to change the only route parameter keeping the whole url same in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have Url like the following:
http://localhost:4200/realms/111/(realmOutlet:groups)

I want to update only 111 to 222 on button click in the shared component. realmOutlet may vary on other pages. Please suggest me how to achieve this route. I have pasted routes used in my project below:

```
 {
        path: 'realms/:id',
        component: RealmsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'groups',
                component: GroupsComponent,
                outlet: 'realmOutlet'
            },
            {
                path: 'group/:id',
                component: GroupComponent,
                outlet: 'realmOutlet'
            },
            {
                path: 'members',
                component: MembersComponent,
                outlet: 'realmOutlet'
            },
            {     
                path: 'member/:id',
                component: MemberComponent,
                outlet: 'realmOutlet'
            },
            {
                path: 'invites',
                component: InvitationsComponent,
                outlet: 'realmOutlet'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you do `[routerLink]="['realms', id, 'groups']"`? Does it not keep routing to the same `realmOutlet` outlet since it's set in the route? If not, try `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'realmOutlet': ['realms', id, 'groups'] } }]"`

Comment: I want to find the 'groups' from Url.